# MySQL JDBC ResultSet next method returns null even though there are more results?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Java application that uses a Statement to execute a query that should return about 100,000 records. I iterate over the ResultSet, calling the next method to retrieve each record. The number of records I receive varies from one execution to another. No exception is thrown, the next method simply returns null.

What could explain this behavior?

Comment: `ResultSet.next()` cannot return null, since it returns a boolean.  Do you mean it returns `false`?

Comment: BTW: I can't repeat this often enough: If you want a good answer, post some code.

Comment: +1 for code; and did you try getting metadata from result set and inspecting that? hope you are using a decent debugger.

Comment: Code won't necessarily make the problem apparent if it's threading, unless we want to cite the lack of locking or synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark: are you somehow handling/access the same ResultSet from multiple threads at once? Symptoms certainly sound like a synchronization issue might be at play.